# How to transfer a live data stream from a linux headless system to a windows machine?

Tags: linux, windows

I've recently been working with the [NAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nao_%28robot%29). We're trying to connect the [NavChip](http://www.intersense.com/pages/16/16/) to it and do some experiments related to robot navigation. The NAO uses a modified 2.6 linux kernel on it's geode system. I've managed to make my NavChip work on it (needed to compile the linux cp210x kernel module etcetera). I can therefore run a C program that came with the NavChip and collect data from it. However, the data can only be logged on the local file system. I'd like to stream this data over the network to a windows machine, since all the processing is MATLAB based. Would anyone have any suggestions on how I can send this data from the NAO to a windows machine?

The NAO's system is pretty limited. It has ssh, and some common utilities like cat etc., but nothing advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem properly but I think you've answered your own question you mentioned ssh is installed so why not just scp the file? Using some ssh client on the windows box to remotely connect and download relevent log file.

If you really do need to push the file from the remote host to local machine (rather then connect to remote host and download to local) then netcat should work see here: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/06/netcat-a-couple-of-useful-examples/

Other wise just write your own socket program in C and pipe the file accross (should be pretty trivial).

Comment: I could use netcat, but the NAO doesn't have it, unfortunately. Can I scp the file while it's still being logged to? Saving the file and then transferring it isn't what I'm looking to do.

I can write a socket program in C, I know how to do it when both my systems are linux. I don't know if the windows socket specification is compatible with the linux one. I'll look into that.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to log data to a file and then copy the file. I want to send the data that the sensor generates in realtime to a windows machine (for realtime processing).

Comment: Ahh I understand the problem now, its actually closely related to my job - I work with Industrial control systems we use OPC to send data from sensors (usually thermocouples pressure gauges etc. in realtime), unfortunately that is Windows only. Depending on how the log file is written you have a few options, does it write to the file only for certain 'events' (i.e if sensor exceeds a threshold value write out to log file) or is it a constant stream of data (in which case is it buffered and do you have to send a command to flush the buffer to disk?).

Comment: After I send a certain hex signal (a "start streaming" command: it has some commands, to set registers for packet formats, data/baud rates and start/stop streaming etcetera) to my sensor, it continuously streams data (until I send the "stop streaming" command). It doesn't appear to be buffered either. I would be able to do it if I had to send the data to another linux system, using simple socket programming. However, linux to windows is a little bit of a bother (since I really know very little about windows)

Comment: Unfortunately my background is Unix programming as well can't really help with windows side of things. I know there are programs like Cygwin to give you a posix environment in Windows that may help.